# Error defining a task on Amazon Container Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli

But to run the

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --family --container-definitions wordpress file: //wordpress.json"
```

is giving the following error below:

```
Error parsing parameter '--container-definitions': Invalid JSON: Expecting object: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

JSON received: {

My wordpress.json:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "wordpress",
      "links": [
        "mysql"
      ],
      "image": "wordpress",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "memory": 500,
      "cpu": 10
    },
    {
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
          "value": "password"
        }
      ],
      "name": "mysql",
      "image": "mysql",
      "cpu": 10,
      "memory": 500,
      "essential": true
    }
  ],
  "family": "wordpress"
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the **space** between `file:` and `//wordpress.json`

Comment: Running the command "aws ecs register-task-definition --family hello_world --container-definitions file://wordpress.json" returns the error:

Error parsing parameter '--container-definitions': Invalid JSON: Expecting object: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
JSON received: {

Answer (score 0):

The correct aws cli command for registration of the Task is

`aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json  file://wordpress.json`